# Is it better to pass an object or the objects id?

Tags: php, yii

This is a hypothetical question that I would simply like to hear some opinions on. Similar questions have been asked, but I didn't think the answers were very clear/satisfying.

So, let's say that I have a function that pays a number of individuals. These individuals are grouped together in an object found which is created from a query into the database.

For the function, i have two options. 
I could either

1. Have it take in the $list_id (which I can use to query the database and find all of the individuals I should pay)

or I can

1. Pass in the object of individuals 
   This means I already would have queried the database with the list_id.

Are there any best practices involved with this? Does passing an object of data from the controller to the model take more memory/slower than simply calling the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends. If you can work with just the IDs because you can easily manipulate the database with PDO or direct sql and don't need a model, then yes, it's faster and lower on memory.

If you however need the model, because you have additional logic there in an `afterSave()` or something or already have the models loaded, because you retrived the IDs from them, then it's better to pass the models along imho. These are are php objects and are always passed by reference, so they don't consume additional memory.

Another thing is, that it's sometimes easier to just make a `$model->save()` in a loop of an array of model than set up a more complicated sql query by hand. Plus you would loose the model events, which is maybe also a concern.

Comment: How is it faster? Objects are passed by reference, so it should be equally cheap, right?

Comment: @W.B. I meant the overall cost. If you need to aquire the objects first it would cost more. Just passing them would be euqal to pass IDs I guess.